# Zend Twitter: Connecting

Tags: zend-framework, twitter

I have the following code:

```
        $twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array('username' => $this->site->twitter_username, 'accessToken' => $this->site->twitter_password));
        $response = $twitter->account->verifyCredentials();
        print_r($response);
        $twitter->account->endSession();
```

My username is my Login Username on twitter, my $this->site->twitter_password is my Access Token (oauth_token)

Yet I get:

```
Zend_Rest_Client_Result Object ( [_sxml:protected] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [request] => /account/verify_credentials.xml [error] => Could not authenticate you. ) [_errstr:protected] => )
```

I'm unsure where I'm going wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I recently blogged about this and have included some instructions that should get you going, let me know if you need any more pointers.

[PHP Using Zend framework to display new tweets as KDE notifications](http://wes.limethinking.co.uk/2011/03/31/php-using-zend-framework-to-display-new-tweets-as-kde-notifications/)